# Lubuntu taskbar doesn't update window titles

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, taskbar, pcmanfm, lxpanel

I've recently installed Lubuntu 15.04, and everything is fine, except one (very annoying) little thing. My taskbar correctly shows all windows, displaying their title, but it doesn't update those titles as I browse different websites in Firefox, or go to different directories in PCManFM. So, the titles shown in the taskbar are those that the windows had when they were added to the list, they don't update anymore.

I've found that if I execute

```
lxpanelctl restart
```

titles are updated, but they don't change anymore. I've tried to create a new panel from scratch, and the wrong behaviour still appears.

It might seem a minor thing, but it's very annoying when you have three different windows labeled just "Mozilla Firefox" or "PcManFM".

**Update:** If I recreate the lxpanel profile (by using the template at `/usr/share/lxpanel/profile/Lubuntu/`) it works again, but as soon as I customize the default panel and reboot, it stops working.

The following screenshot illustrates the problem:

[image: Taskbar window titles not updating]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. It seemed clear that the problem was with some of my customizations to the default panel, so I've performed each one, step by step, and I've found that the taskbar stops working properly when I remove the desktop switcher from the panel (I don't use multiple desktops). If I re-add it, everything works fine again.

It makes sense, because desktop switcher is one of the few panel plugins that needs feedback from the desktop, in order to show window miniatures and its placement. It seems that when no desktop switcher is present in a panel, lxpanel stops receiving updates from windows, so taskbar plugin (which also needs this updates to update titles) stops working too. Looks like a bug to me, I've [filled it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxpanel/+bug/1493333).

Comment: (+1) strange, but this solved my problem (Lubuntu 1704) thanks for sharing the solution!